# Database Selecting Multiple Rows Based on Multiple Values

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am designing a database to store cocktail name and their ingredients.
The database has following structure.

```
Drinks      
ID  NAME    IMGURL
1   A      http://
2   B      http://
3   C      http://

Ingredients 
ID  NAME
1   Water
2   SugarSyrup
3   Rum
4   Vodka
5   Gin
6   Tonic
7   Orange Juice
8   Whiskey

DRINKS_INGREDIENTS          
ID  DRINKSID    INGREDIENTSID   Quantity
1   1   1   30
2   1   4   90
3   1   6   60
4   2   8   30
5   2   1   30
6   2   2   30
7   2   3   10
8   2   4   30
9   3   5   60
10  3   6   60

Stocks  
StockID IngredientID
1   5
2   6
```

I want to select only the **DRINKSIDs** from **DRINKS_INGREDIENTS** table where the ingredients equals to the ones we have in stock.ex- if we only have Gin and Tonic in Stock, then it should return only DrinkID=3.If we have all the ingredients in stock, then it will return the all the DrinkIDs in the list.

We can also assume that the **stocks are infinite** so quantity check is not required.

I am using sqlite database and I am not sure how to write a query to make this work.

Comment: How will you decide whether you have all ingredients doe a drink  are in stock?

Comment: Someone updates those values everyday manually and so we know that beforehand.The values are stored in an array of Strings.

Comment: But I want to ask that for drink A which ingredients you should check sameway fror drink B which ingredients to be checked

Comment: Probably my question is not clear, so I will make another attempt at it.So I have a database of drinks but I only have certain ingredients in stock.I only want to present the user with drinks which can be made with the ones we have in stock.So essentially I want a query which will only return the DRINKID for drinks whose ingredients are currently in stock.Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand but my question is still pending that how can i decide which drinks want which ingredients to be used?

Comment: The third table DRINKS_INGREDIENTS contains the DRINKID as well as INGREDIENTIDS so by running a query we can find out which ingrediennts are needed by a certain drink.For example, for Drink A, the ID is 1 which in third table corresponds to INgredients 1,4,6 which is Vodka ,Gin and Water.

Comment: Then how can you decide which INgredients is not available for which drink

Comment: Do you have a table with ingredients in stock (with quantities) too?

Comment: Yes I have a table with stocks.Right now we can assume that the quantity is infinite..so the table only contains the ingredients in stock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find what drinks you can make given ingredients in stock you can do an inner join between two queries. The first will give you the count of ingredients needed to make each drink, and the other will give you the count of ingredients in stock for each drink. By joining the queries on drinks.ID and count you'll get the drinks that have all ingredients needed in stock.

This query should do what you want:

```
select drinks.name from (
    select d.NAME, di.DRINKSID, count(*) as cnt 
    from DRINKS_INGREDIENTS di
    inner join Drinks d on d.ID = di.DRINKSID
    group by d.name, di.DRINKSID
) drinks
inner join (
    select di.DRINKSID, count(*) as cnt 
    from DRINKS_INGREDIENTS di
    inner join stock s on di.INGREDIENTSID = s.IngredientID
    group by di.DRINKSID
) stock 
on drinks.DRINKSID = stock.DRINKSID
    and drinks.cnt = stock.cnt;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cf751/2)

It would be easy to modify it to take quantity in stock in account too, just add quantity to the stocks table, and modify the join in the second query to include s.quantity >= di.quantity. See this [sample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/50164/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot.The solution looks great .The quantity check is an added advantage.